# Count records based on a column with a part of the same value

Tags: sql, select, count

I have a table similar to this:

Table A22

| Id | Item | Location |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 1234-01 |
| 2 | a | 1234-01 |
| 3 | a | 1234-01 |
| 4 | a | 1234-01 |
| 5 | a | 2345-01 |
| 6 | b | 1234-01 |
| 7 | b | 1234-01 |
| 8 | b | 1234-01 |
| 9 | b | 1234-01 |
| 10 | b | 2345-01 |

I would like to compare the first 4 values in `Location` and count all locations which have the same 4 values and the same item.

I try this query and similar ones but I can't get the correct count:

```
select  
    a.item,
    a.location,
    sum(a.id) as 'count'
from
    a22 a,
    a22 b
where 
    1 = 1
    and substring(a.location, 1, 4) = substring(b.LOCATION_NAME, 1, 4)
group by 
    a.item, a.location
```

Edit: Desired output should be like this:

| Item | Location | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1234-01 | 4 |
| a | 2345-01 | 1 |
| b | 1234-01 | 4 |
| b | 2345-01 | 1 |

Any suggestions?

Comment: The name `id` implies the column is unique.

Comment: "...the first 4 values in Location..." -- In relational databases rows do not have inherent ordering or position. You'll need to explicitly tell us the *ordering* to decide which ones are the "first 4 values".

Comment: select count('dracula'), item, substring(location,1,4) from a22 group by item, substring(location,1,4);

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**almost 30 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Can you share the output you expect to get for this sample data?

Comment: Sorry, i made a few mistakes in my post last night so i edited it. The id is off course unique and i also added the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

[Bryan Dellinger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2744722/bryan-dellinger) gave me [the correct answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69441630/count-records-based-on-a-column-with-a-part-of-the-same-value/69451876#comment122739621_69441630):

```
select count('dracula'),
       item,
       substring(location,1,4)
    from a22
    group by 
        item,
        substring(location,1,4);
```